# Is there any way to add multiple foreign keys for mysql columns but they should be refer to a row in other table?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am trying to find a query like this. Is it possible in mysql?

```
ALTER TABLE `table1`
ADD CONSTRAINT my_constraint_name
FOREIGN KEY (some_id, some_other_id) REFERENCES `table2`(id, other_id);
```

My scenario is, `table1.some_id` should be referred to `table2.id` Where it should also meet `table1.some_other_id` is from the same row of table2 and that is `table2.other_id`

Comment: Yes it is. Did you try in mysql?

Comment: Yes I tried it. I am getting this error 
`#1005 - Can't create table 'test_db.#sql-415_186' (errno: 150) (Details…)`

Answer (score 1):

> **Yes, this is possible in MySQL.**

This should work perfectly fine.

```
ALTER TABLE table1
ADD CONSTRAINT table1_fk FOREIGN KEY (`column1`, `column2`) 
REFERENCES table2 (column1, column2);
```

Comment: ...unless column1 in one table has a different data type than column1 in the other, or column2 has the same problem.  Foreign key constraints require the same data type for referencing and referenced.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - Yes, of course. I left that part out.